# RabbitMQ user permission to pub/sub on a pre-created queue

Tags: permissions, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a use case where i need to create a user and give him permission to only pub/sub on an existing queue, here's an example:

- Vhost "mainvhost" (is the same for all users)
- Inside the vhost, i have Q-foo and Q-bar queues
- User "foo" can only pub/sub to Q-foo
- User "bar" can only pub/sub to Q-bar

I didnt get the way to setup such user management policy, the only way i found is to create one vhost for each user, this way, user will have full access in its own vhost but there's a big downside: i have a consumer application that's subscribing to all queues and wait user inputs, if every user has its own vhost, then i need to have 1 consumer per vhost since i didnt get a way to consume from multiple vhosts using same connection to rabbitmq.

Answer (score 24):

small point of clarity: you should publish to an exchange, and subscribe to a queue. that being said, you may want an "ex-foo" and "ex-bar" for your exchanges... one per user, basically. it can be done differently, but this would work.

---

when adding permissions, you can use regular expressions to set what the user is allowed to do.

for example, using [the rabbitmqctl command line](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html) to set permissions, you can do this:

`rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /myvhost tonyg "^tonyg-.*" ".*" ".*"`

> This command instructs the RabbitMQ broker to grant the user named tonyg access to the virtual host called /myvhost, with configure permissions on all resources whose names starts with "tonyg-", and write and read permissions on all resources.

note that the order of permissions in the three "quotes" is: configure, write, read.

in your case, you would want to set permissions like this:

- vhost: mainvhost
- user: foo
- configure: ""
- write: "^[ex-foo|Q-foo].*"
- read: "^[ex-foo|Q-foo].*"

this will grant permissions for the `foo` user to read and write to any exchange or queue that starts with `ex-foo` or `Q-foo`

You may be able to get away with something more restrictive, like

- write: "^ex-foo.*"
- read: "^Q-foo.*"

I'm not sure if you need write permissions to the queue, when publishing through an exchange. I haven't had to set up this level of granularity in my security, yet.

Comment: In the case of direct publish to queue permission to default exchange amq.default should be added ^(amq.default|Q-foo)$

Comment: This does not prevent the same user from sending the msg to another queue(eg. P-foo) via direct exchange.

Comment: @vikram2784 is your comment in response to John Smith or to the main answer by Derick Bailey?