# Configure specific queues on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am working on project, which uses RabbitMQ and will be very large in the future. Because of this, I would not like to create RabbitMQ queues ad-hoc, but instead specify them from some config file / allow list.

**My Goal:**

I would like strictly limit my clients from using queues other than `employee_queue` and `company_queue`.

**My Rationale:**
If developers will make a typo in queue name (eg. `eeemployee_queue`), I want them to know immediately, instead creating big queue, which will not be useful at all.

Any reccomended way how to achieve this? Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood - in which case apologies, maybe you can clarify in the question, but: (a) "_I would like strictly limit my clients from using queues other than employee_queue and company_queue._" Grant [permissions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) to your client user IDs to only be able to access these 2 queues.

Comment: And (b) "_instead of creating big queue_" - see questions such as [prohibit consumer from creating queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645258/rabbitmq-prohibit-consumer-from-creating-queues) (the Spring Boot part of that question is not relevant).  Also see questions such as [RabbitMQ user permission to pub/sub on a pre-created queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379506/12567365).